# What is the smallest prime factor of a composite number?

Tags: prime-numbers, factoring

**Question :** What is the smallest prime factor of a composite number?

Let us consider few examples $128$ definitely $2$. so for all even numbers we have $2$ as a smallest prime factor. Now let us consider the example of $33$: it is $3$.

To me it appears that it will be very small with respect to $n$

Comment: Greatest that it can go is $\sqrt n$. Consider $n = p^2$, where $p$ is a prime.

Comment: In case it isn't clear why the bound is $\sqrt n$, suppose that $n = \prod_{i=1}^k p_i$ for some primes $\sqrt n < p_1 \le p_2 \le \cdots \le p_k$. Then $n \ge p_1 p_2 > (\sqrt n)^2 = n$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smallest prime factor of a positive composite integer is never greater than the square root of the number.